# Bitcoind - establishing SSL RPC connection

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, rpc, bitcoin

I installed a bitcoind server on ubuntu and was able to connect to it via RPC with a java client. Now I want to enable SSL to secure the connection. I followed this instructions (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon) and created the "server.pem" and "server.cert" on my server and set the flag "rpcssl=1" in the config.

On the java client, I changed the URL from "http" to "https", but I get the error:
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Do I need to install some certificate or key on the client machine as well or should the client to be able to connect without any certificate?

Comment: I think you do need a cert and a key on your side as well.

Comment: You should open this question to the bitcoin-specialized sub-forum: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/